# Phonegap :Angularjs find in Json Array

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, json, cordova

i am finding the id in Json, Works fine in Browsers

When i Convert [Phonegap] and Deploy it Mobile, it showing the below error

```
MetaDiseaseApp.controller('detailsController', function($scope,$http,$stateParams) {
    $http({method: 'POST', url: 'assets/data/diseases.json'})
    .success(function(data)
    {
      $scope.disease = data.diseases.find(disease => disease.id_disease === idDisease);
    });
});
```

Error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >`

I Think i have to find some ohter similar solution to find id in my Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery.map(data.diseases, function(obj) {
 if(obj.id_disease === idDisease)
    $scope.disease = obj;// or return obj.name, whatever
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `arrow functions` in es6 is not supported.

Try following

```
data.diseases.find(function (disease) {
  return disease.id_disease === idDisease;
});
```

============================================================

Updated: `Array.prototype.find()` is part of es6 as well. You might want to avoid and replace all code written with new feature introduced in es6.

```js
var jsObjects = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}, {
  a: 3,
  b: 4
}, {
  a: 5,
  b: 6
}, {
  a: 7,
  b: 8
}];

var filterObj = jsObjects.filter(function(e) {
  return e.b == 6;
});

console.log(filterObj[0]);
```

Comment: TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'find' Coming